# UMASK function in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, umask

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
void main()
{
    umask(0000);
    creat("a.txt",666);
}
```

My expected output is, the file created with the name "a.txt" with the permission as "rwrwrw". But, the output is as follows.

Output:

```
$ ls -l a.txt 
--w--wx-wT 1 mohanraj mohanraj 0 Sep 11 19:04 a.txt
$
```

The umask is set to 0. So, I expected the file is created with the default file permission with 666. But, it gives some other output. So, 
How umask internally worked. And How do I get the expected result.

Comment: Did you read [umask(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) before asking here?

Comment: As a colleague of mine used the above example in code, I thought I'd mention for the benefit of future readers that `umask(0000);` can be simplified to `umask(0);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file creation mode you specified is in decimal format.  File creation modes are typically specified in octal, so you should prefix the number with a leading 0, which tells the compiler **it is an octal constant**.

```
creat("a.txt",0666);
```

Decimal 666 = octal 1232, which matches up with the result you got.

Please refer to your friendly man page (`man 2 umask`) or to [this one](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html).

Answer (score 2):

> --w--wx-wT

1 * 512 + 2 * 64 + 3 * 8 + 2 = 666

It did exactly what you asked for. Try using `0666` instead.